# CAShapeLayer not Animated

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am having trouble figuring out how to get animation working.  I have a UIView called BallView .  I can draw a large red circle fine.  I want that circle to fade from red to green.  I setup a `CAShapeLayer` and `CABasicAnimation` in my view's initializer but the animation doesn't work.  Here is my initializer:

```
- (void)initHelper:(UIColor*)c {    
  CAShapeLayer* sl = (CAShapeLayer*) self.layer;
  sl.fillColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
  sl.path = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.bounds] CGPath];

  CABasicAnimation *colorAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"fillColor"];
  colorAnim.duration = 5.0;
  colorAnim.fromValue = [UIColor redColor];
  colorAnim.toValue = [UIColor greenColor];
  colorAnim.repeatCount = 10;
  colorAnim.autoreverses = YES;
  [sl addAnimation:colorAnim forKey:@"fillColor"];
}
```

Comment: Where did you call this method? Is it BallView's Initialization method?

Comment: I override the other init methods.  Those init methods call initHelper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your from and to values are not right, you should set

```
 colorAnim.fromValue = (__bridge id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
 colorAnim.toValue = (__bridge id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have put animations in the init method, because at that time this view is being added to the view hierarchy. Try to move the initHelper method out of init method and expose it in BallView.h, thus you can call it whenever you want in the view Controller, you can add it in viewDidAppear method. If you don't want to do that,you can simply delay the fire time of the initHelper like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(initHelper:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```